# Azure functions post issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Hi Iam new to Azure functions i am using VS 2017 15.4 and running helloworld function app on local. i was able to do get request on this function but when i perform post on same uri it gives.

mscorlib: Exception while executing function: HelloWorld. System.Net.Http.Formatting: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Object' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.

can you tell me what i forgot bold line is giving problem in post request, i tried with contentType and without ContentType; with body and without body.

How can i parse Json object in request body in azure function. one way i could was to parse it in string then deserialized using jsonconvert. is their any better way of doing it like valueproviders modelbinders etc.

```
[FunctionName("HelloWorld")]
public static async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // parse query parameter
        string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
            .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
            .Value;

        // Get request body
        *dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();*

        // Set name to query string or body data
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name == null
            ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
            : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
    }.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work assuming the `Content-Type` header on your HTTP request is set to `application/json`.

Note that if the header's value is `multipart/form-data`, then this is a known bug documented [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2009).

Comment: that worked for me, is there a way that i can parse my json into class, i tried to parse it in string and then deserialize using jsonconvert.deserialize<T>  can it be done automatically.

Comment: If you have a class with type `SampleType`, then changing `req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>()` to `req.Content.ReadAsAsync<SampleType>()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

As Connor said as long as the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json` in your request this code will work fine. An issue I have run into though is that the add header functionality when testing azure functions in azure portal doesn't seem to work in this case.

If you can send a request to your function from outside of the test section of azure functions this should work fine.